How to connect Simulink to Simscape
I designed wind turbine power generator, converter and load and I am trying to use converted power to power electrolyzer to design temperature control system. but the voltage from the Simulink design does not connect to electrolyzer + and - port even when I use Simulink-PS converter. What should I do to connect them together?
Wind turbine power generator, converter:

